# Erro when dotnet new webapi error NU1301: Unable to load service index to source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.`

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

when I run the command

`dotnet new wepapi`

the following error is logged

`/home/.../class8.2.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load service index to source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.`

I've tried several settings in nuget.config but nothing worked

What can I do?

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

WeatherForecast.cs

```
namespace class8._2;

public class WeatherForecast
{
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

It's default code when I exec dotnet new webapi

Comment: show your startup.cs file code

Comment: @viveknuna I replied

Comment: Edit your question and add details to it.

Comment: Sounds like you can’t hit the NuGet package service